# Vim command mapping

Tags: vim, vimrc

My question is about mapping a multi-part command to a single key combo.

In my .vimrc, I've got the following line:

```
nnoremap <leader>ss :w\|:silent !execute_external_script > output_of_script.txt\|:redraw!<cr>
```

As you can see, I've got three commands I want to execute when i press `<leader>ss`.  First, write the file, then execute my external script (the script runs a unit test).  Unfortunately, my terminal doesn't redraw Vim after executing the shell command.  So I tried appending that `:redraw!` command, apparently that command is getting passed to the shell, not to Vim, because I'm getting this error:

`bash: :redrawecho: command not found`.

How do I write the command so that the script executes in the shell, then redraw executes in Vim?  (Also, as a bonus, could anyone explain what `<cr>` does?)

Comment: According to: http://swaroopch.com/notes/vim_en-introduction/ <CR> means "a ‘c’arriage ‘r’eturn, i.e., the enter key."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the `:!` command takes the remainder of the command-line as arguments. To concatenate other Vim commands, you can wrap the command with `:execute`:

```
nnoremap <leader>ss :w\|:silent execute '!execute_external_script > output_of_script.txt'\|:redraw!<cr>
```

Alternatively, you can just issue multiple command-lines, separated by `<CR>`; after all, a mapping is just a fixed macro:

```
nnoremap <leader>ss :w\|:silent !execute_external_script > output_of_script.txt<cr>:redraw!<cr>
```

Another note: Instead of escaping the `\|` command separator, the usual way is to use the special `<Bar>` keycode instead; see the full list at `:help keycodes`; this also explains that `<CR>` stands for *carriage return*.